# Error in function Mclust() in package mclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, expectation-maximization

First, let's take a look of `mydata`:

```
head(mydata,10)

   LONGITUDE LATITUDE
1   121.7779  39.0476
2   121.5210  38.8771
3   121.6259  38.9224
4   121.5907  38.8980
5   121.5865  38.8816
6   121.5808  38.9121
7   121.5806  38.8843
8   121.5907  38.8992
9   121.7586  39.0380
10  121.6061  38.9035

dim(mydata)
[1] 716213      2

 summary(mydata)
 LONGITUDE        LATITUDE    
 Min.   :121.1   Min.   :38.72  
 1st Qu.:121.6   1st Qu.:38.91  
 Median :121.6   Median :38.93  
 Mean   :121.6   Mean   :38.95  
 3rd Qu.:121.6   3rd Qu.:38.99  
 Max.   :122.2   Max.   :39.40
```

The whole size of mydata is less than 20Mb.

Now, I want to conduct the cluster with mydata, I use `Mclust()` in package `mclust`, which is know as EM (expectation maximization).

```
fit_em <- Mclust(mydata)
```

To my surprise, after I input the code, I have waited for over 1 hour to get the result, is an Error. The detailed info is:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1910.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In hcVVV(data = c(121.7779, 121.521, 121.6259, 121.5907, 121.5865,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
2: In double(ld) :
  Reached total allocation of 8191Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In double(ld) :
  Reached total allocation of 8191Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In double(ld) :
  Reached total allocation of 8191Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In double(ld) :
  Reached total allocation of 8191Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

What is going wrong with mydata and my code, what should I do if I want to conduct the cluster with mydata?

Comment: R tries to use 2 Tb of memory.

Comment: Thank you, I know what the error means, and I want to know whether there is any solution in other R package

Comment: According to your question, you don't seem to realize what 2 Tb are. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `Mclust` is implemented, it will use *quadratic* memory.

Do the math. 716213 * 716213 * 8 bytes per double.

This is not necessary, but the default operation. You can use `initialization` to choose a less expensive initialization. But to cluster large geo data sets, you should have a look at ELKI, too. If I'm not mistaken, its EM implementation should only need linear memory.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! ELKI is a framework written in Java? Is there any solution I can conduct in R?

Comment: I don't use R much, its syntax gives me headache. But you could try RJava?

Comment: Have a look at the `initialization` option of `Mclust`.